# Linux - Bash to login to a machine and then become root

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, sshpass

I am trying to login to Linux box with my regular user and then become root using a bash script. My user is in the sudoers file so it can become root.

The normal process would be the following:

```
$ssh regularuser@machine
regularuser@machine's password:
[regularuser@machine ~]$
[regularuser@machine ~]$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for regularuser:
[root@machine ~]$
```

I searched all over to do this but all I could find doesn't do exactly what I need. I also tried using #!/usr/bin/expect but it doesn't work.

```
===========================================================================
```

My working bash (access.sh) is as follows **but it asks me for the password after issuing the "sudo su -" command**:

```
#!/bin/bash
machine=$1
ssh -t regularuser@$machine "sudo su -"

$ sh access.sh machine
regularuser@machine's password:
[sudo] password for regularuser:
[root@machine ~]# exit
logout
Connection to machine closed.

===========================================================================
```

Attempt #1 - When I tried the following I got "**/usr/bin/expect: No such file or directory**"

```
#!/bin/bash
machine=$1
echo "Password?"
read -s password

expect -c '
    spawn ssh regularuser@'"$machine"'
    expect "Password: "
    send '"$password\r"'
'
```

Attempt #2 - Same result

```
#!/bin/bash
machine=$1
echo "Password?"
read -s password

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn ssh regularuser@$machine
expect "Password: "
send "${password}\r"
EOF
```

Attempt #3 - Doesn't work either. It gives me "**unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''**"

```
#!/bin/bash
machine=$1
echo "Password?"
read -s password

ssh -t regularuser@$machine "echo $password | sudo -S su -"


$ sh access.sh machine
Password?
regularuser@machine's password:
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Connection to vm-all-all-ad-test-packages closed.
```

I cannot do "sshpass -p "$password" ssh root@$machine" either because the password of my regular user is different from root's

I tried pretty much everything out there but with no success.

Any ideas?!!

Comment: Why are you using passwords and not ssh keys?  By default, sshd permits root logins, so you could set up a ssh key on that machine and add it to your `ssh.config` or use the `-i` switch.  Unless, like me, you have prevented any root logins via SSH.

Comment: I am afraid this is the requirement and root login it not permitted. No ssh keys must be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that you bring `sshpass` up. `sshpass` is designed to bypass `ssh`'s requirement that the password be given interactively. The problem you are facing, and the reason `expect` doesn't work, is that `sudo` does precisely the same trick, for precisely the same reason.

Potential solutions, in decreasing order of how much I recommend them:

1. Get the admin to allow you key-based authentication directly to root.
2. Change the sudoers file to allow your user to run that specific command without authenticating with `sudo`.
3. Convince `sshpass` to do its usual trick on the `sudo` prompt. I have not tried it, but it may be as simple as doing `sshpass -p password sudo something`. If not, I seem to remember the latest versions of `sshpass` have a way to change its expected password prompt (similar to what `expect` is doing). The latest commit in the `sshpass` svn seems to be it, but I am fairly certain I did not get around to actually releasing a version with this capability.

**WARNING**: Do #3 at your risk. The implications of #3 is that you are storing, in recoverable form, the password for your user in some file system. Do everything you can to avoid this option.

**Update**: Version 1.06 of sshpass is now on the sourceforge download site. It is confirmed to work with `sudo`, and it contains the password prompt specifier to help. Still not recommending this solution.

Comment: Thanks Shachar for your comments. I am afraid I cannot do any.

Answer (score 0):

```
:- you can try these commands in your linux terminal --:
```

> If you know the password

```
  $ su     
      
    OR        
      
  $ su -
```

> If you don't know[remember/set] the password

```
  $ sudo su    
           
     OR             
           
  $ sudo su -
```